# NestJS-Prisma How to Apply Count Relations

Tags: nestjs, prisma

I was trying to follow the official prisma documentation about implement the count relations with [prisma client](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/aggregation-grouping-summarizing#count). In the official documentation, it provides an example:

```
const usersWithCount = await prisma.user.findMany({
  select: {
    _count: {
      select: { posts: true },
    },
  },
})
```

Follow this documentation, I created the following codes in my NestJS project:

```
@ApiDefaultResponse({status: 200, description:'Successfully returned customer count'})
@ApiBadRequestResponse({status:400, description: "Bad Request"})
@Get('Count')
async getCustomersCount(){
    return this.prismaService.clinic.findMany({
        select: {
            _count: {
                select: {customers: true}
            }
        }
    })

}
```

However, this gave me an error of

```
Type '{ _count: { select: { customers: true; }; }; }' is not assignable to type 'clinicSelect'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and '_count' does not exist in type 'clinicSelect'.
```

And for the auto-generated clinicSelect type: I have

```
  export type clinicSelect = {
    clinic_id?: boolean
    clinic_name?: boolean
    clinic_address?: boolean
    customers?: boolean | customerFindManyArgs
    isActive?: boolean
  }
```

The models I used here is similar to the one prisma used in the documentation, the clinic and customers are many to many relationship.

Other than this one, I can apply other methods showed in the official documentation, for this count relations,

> The ability to count relations is available in version 2.20.0 and
> later.

And my prisma version is 2.30.

```
prisma -v
Environment variables loaded from .env
prisma                : 2.30.0
@prisma/client        : 2.30.0
Current platform      : windows
```

So my question is, why I cannot apply this count relations in my NestJS code? Is this just an issue with the prisma client or It should be written in another way? Thanks for the help!

Here is my scheme:

```
model clinic {
  clinic_id      Int        @id @unique
  clinic_name    String
  clinic_address String
  /// @DtoRelationRequired
  /// @DtoRelationCanConnectOnCreate
  /// @DtoRelationCanConnectOnUpdate
  customers      customer[]
  isActive       Boolean    @default(true)
}

model customer {
  customer_id         Int          @id @unique
  customer_first_name String?      @db.VarChar(50)
  customer_last_name  String?      @db.VarChar(50)
  customer_address    String?      @db.VarChar(250)
  /// @DtoRelationRequired
  /// @DtoRelationCanConnectOnCreate
  /// @DtoRelationCanConnectOnUpdate
  clinics             clinic[]
  orders              order_info[]
  patient_info        patient[]
  payment_method      String?
  phone               String?
  email               String?
  isActive Boolean @default(true)
}
```

Comment: If that could help, your generated type ClinicSelect should look like 
export type clinicSelect = {
    clinic_id?: boolean
    clinic_name?: boolean
    clinic_address?: boolean
    customers?: boolean | customerFindManyArgs
    isActive?: boolean
   **_count?: boolean | ClinicCountOutputTypeArgs**
  }.
Can you share your prisma schema ?

Comment: @RomainTAILLANDIER Hi Romain, thanks for the help. I just updated my schema. I understand your  comment, based on the official document inside the modelSelect, there should be a _count and inside that model_count, it should have a select inside it. But I cannot find that kind of relation inside the autogenerated type. I might be able to write one by myself. But those types are auto generated by Prisma and it would be refreshed every time I do a prisma generate. So I was wondering whether there is a way to perform the count relations like the one in the official document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out myself. This is a preview feature in prisma 2.30. To solve this, just upgrade both prisma and prisma/client version to 3.30 with

```
npm install prisma@3 @prisma/client@3
```

Even though the count relations is added since prisma 2.21. But from there release note, this function is generally available in prisma 3.01. So, in 2.30, this function might not be available. To use it in prisma 2.30, [the preview feature needs to be enabled](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/preview-features/client-preview-features/#enabling-a-prisma-client-preview-feature).

> Enabling a Prisma Client preview feature To enable a Prisma Client
> Preview feature:
>
> Add the Preview feature flag to the generator block:
>
> generator client {   provider        = "prisma-client-js"
> previewFeatures = ["mongoDb"] } Re-generate the client:
>
> npx prisma generate  If you are using Visual Studio Code and the
> Preview feature is not available in your .ts file after generating the
> client, run the TypeScript: Restart TS server command.

Prisma 3.30 Release Notes

> Select Relation Count is Generally Available Select Relation Count
> allows you to count the number of related records by passing _count to
> the select or include options and then specifying which relation
> counts should be included in the resulting objects via another select.
>
> Select Relation Count helps you query counts on related models, for
> example, counting the number of posts per user:
>
> const users = await prisma.user.findMany({   include: {
> _count: {
> select: { posts: true },
> },   }, }) Expand to view the structure of the returned `users` If you've been using this Preview feature, you can remove the
> selectRelationCount flag from previewFeatures in your Prisma Schema.

See the upgrade reference [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/upgrade-guides/upgrading-versions/upgrading-to-prisma-3).
See Prisma Release Notes [here](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/releases).